# I made image detection system using opencv in python but its now switching on the camera, can anyone please tell what can be the issue?

Tags: web-config, python-3.6, runtime.exec

One of my friend said I should study about GUI for turning on the webcam in that system, Is it correct? or any other solution.

I made image detection system using opencv in python but its now switching on the camera, can anyone please tell what can be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, an image input source is essential for an image detection system, and there are many methods to open an image as a source, like `cv2.imread()`, and camera image source is also acceptable in OpenCV, so the detection system turned on the camera is quite reasonable.

The suggestion about WebCam is good if you want to run code in the local but get photos in the remote, else it is unnecessary to use WebCam because OpenCV can use your local camera. A GUI is a choice but not a must.

If you don't want it to open your camera, but just read a picture in your local disk, then you can remove those codes in the system controlling the camera as an image input source and add some codes to make a change for the source from camera to your Disk.